# QTableView notify user input

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I've created a class derived from QTableView. It updates data from another thread and it works.

Now, I want the user to be able to change data shown into the table.

By overriding `flags(const QModelIndex &index) const` of the QAbstractTableModel that I use I'm able to click on a cell and insert a value.

My problem is that I cannot notify when user has finished to edit the cell, and so when editing is finished in the cell the old value is shown.

I've seen that in QTableWidget there's a signal `cellChanged` that seems to do what I want. How can I do the same thing with QTableView and QAbstractTableModel?

Comment: To make editing work you need to override `QAbstractItemModel::setData()` too and explicitly emit `dataChanged()` signal if edit was successful.

Comment: Thanks, I've created the overriden method and I call it when data is changed.